# How to Connect SharePoint CSOM ClientContext using SiteMinder Authentication?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom, siteminder

I have a SharePoint 2013 server that is authenticated using SiteMinder. When users access the SharePoint site using a web browser they are directed to the SiteMinder login page/site and then redirected back to the SharePoint site after successful authentication.

The problem is I'm working on building a console application using the SharePoint CSOM to connected to the SharePoint site to facilitate some task automation. I am having difficulty getting the authentication to work and am always getting a `403 Forbidden` exception with the following code example:

```
using (var context = new ClientContext(url)) {
    context.Credentials = new NetworkCredentials("username", securePassword, "domain");
    context.Load(context.Web, w => w.Title);

    // attempt to execute the query
    // 403 Forbidden WebException thrown here!! Oh Nooooooo!!!!!
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Anyone have any suggestions on how to integrate SiteMinder authentication with this app, or possibly what I am missing to get this working?

Comment: Hi did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Looks like the only solution is to simulate a users HTTP activity using a WebRequest so you can get the correct cookies set to pass in for authentication. The project I was working on at the time was solved by going another way.

Comment: I actually went a different route on this project than through SiteMinder auth.